# How Is it possible to access web app hosted on ubuntu virtual host from other computer on same LAN

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, lan, ubuntu-14.04

The web application is set up in ubuntu installed on virtual box as Guest with Windows 10 as host. The website is accessible from Windows at port

```
localhost:8080
```

But need to access the website from other computers connected on same LAN.Is it possible to do so. How?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you configured networking in your guest. There are multiple networking modes as described in VirtualBox docs: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes.

If possible try using bridged networking for guest services which should be accessible from outside. In typical setups the guest will get an IP from DHCP the same way as your host and should be visible from outside just like your host.

PS. keep in mind that you can hit some problems with bridged networking and windows host (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922055/bridged-networking-not-working-in-virtualbox-under-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Type `ifconfig` in Ubuntu or `ipconfig` in Windows to get to know your IP-address. Then replace `localhost` by that number.

For example, if the IP address of your Windows machine is 192.168.0.2, type `192.168.0.2:8080` to access the webpage.